# Find date in a range

Tags: excel, date, find, vba

I have so many dates in a range like A1: WW1
I mean there is a one date in every cell.

I need a macro that selects only today's date between other dates.

Comment: just loop all cells and compare it with actual date, or if you dont care about data order, you can use autofilter, which can speed up process.

Comment: You need to define your question *much* more clearly. Show us what your data looks like, and explain what you mean by "select only today's date" and what you want to do with that date.

Comment: I only need a macro that finds today's date between cells.I dont need other option like filter or others. Normally i can use ctrl-find but every time, i have to write today's date. so i thought a button-macro pair can do this for me.  it must be the easiest thing, but  i am totally new beginner for vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have consistently filled data. If so we can use used Range to find out Last Row. 
Please Try this code. It will colour the cells having current data. I have used limited range for testing purposes but I think it will work on a larger range also.

```
Sub Highlight()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, lngRow As Long
    Dim strColumn As Integer
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    For strColumn = 1 To lastColumn

        With ActiveSheet
            For lngRow = 2 To lastRow  ' Assuming Row 1 As a header Row
                If IsDate(.Cells(lngRow, strColumn).Value) And CDate(.Cells(lngRow, strColumn).Value) = Date Then
                .Cells(lngRow, strColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            Next lngRow
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: Snapshot highlighting today's date]

Comment: Thank  you so much :)

Comment: @Levent Nergiz In stack overflow saying thanks is by accepting the answer by ticking a right mark below lower triangle on left side. This is one thing which you can only do. I am glad that it worked for you.